# DataTypeConvertor parseDateTime result

Tags: java

I am doing something like this in my program :

```
Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2012-05-29T11:17:04.805-07:00");  
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
```

o/p:

> Tue May 29 13:17:04 CDT 2012

Why is the result showing time of 13:17:04, in the input I have given 11:17:04 and time zone -07:00 which is pacific time zone. Should it not print out 11:17:04 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your timezone - the default one when the program is running is different from the timezone given to the DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime() method and the cal.getTime().toString() method used the default timezone to format the date.

Never use Date.toString() to format Date - a Date only knows the milliseconds from the Epoch time. Instead use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").format(dateObject).

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

class  TestDate
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
      Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2012-05-29T11:17:04.805-07:00");
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
      df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"));
      String date = df.format(cal.getTime());
      System.out.println(date);
   }
}
```

Comment: And watch out. SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. If you create an instance, use it, and throw it away, you are fine. Otherwise, you may need to put it on a ThreadLocal or wrap all use of it in synchronized blocks.